# Jquery intersect selector

Tags: jquery

I'm sure the answer exists on SO somewhere, but I'm at a loss for what terminology to search for.  So apologies if this is a duplicate.

Is there an easy way in jQuery/JS of selecting the elements that "intersect" from the following HTML?

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="source-AAA"/>
  <div id="source-CCC"/>
  <div id="source-EEE"/>
  <div id="source-FFF"/>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div id="BBB"/>
  <div id="CCC"/>
  <div id="DDD"/>
  <div id="FFF"/>
</div>
```

i.e. getting hold of the elements `#CCC` and `#FFF` from `div#second`, based on the fact that these two IDs are in `#first`?

I guess the proper answer is to do the intersect on the server-side (which is possible, but painful, as the two data sets come from different components), but I thought I'd check in case anyone knows of a neat way to do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first have to collect all those IDs, and then build up a CSS selector string accordingly:

```
var divsToSelect = [];

$('#first div').each(function(){
    divsToSelect.push( $(this).attr('id').substr(-3) );
});

$('#' + divsToSelect.join(',#'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TXqw3/

Comment: Clever - I like the join in the second line.  Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I adjusted the example slightly, as it didn't quite work.  Same principal though.  http://jsfiddle.net/udrHk/

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter -

```
$("#second div").filter(function() {
    return $("#first > div[id$=" + this.id + "]").length > 0
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b9NZR/

Comment: This'll run through the DOM too many times (once per every div in the second group).

Comment: `$("#first div").filter(function() { return $("#"+this.id.split('-')[1]).length; });`

Comment: Won't your solution run through every div in the first group though? You'd obviously need to consider speed for any chosen solution, considering number of divs you wanted to compare etc.

Comment: Of course I'm running a loop through all those DIVs. But what I'm talking about is DOM interaction, which is the most expensive operation in Javascript. I'm only interacting with the DOM twice; once to get all those first DIVs, then to select the ones we want. Your solution, on the other hand, queries the DOM once for every DIV in the second group. In addition, I am selecting by ID, which is the fastest way to select elements...

Comment: I thought about that after posting my comment - I see where you're coming from now and take your point. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not clientside?

```
    $('div#first > div').each(function(){
      var fv = $(this).attr('id');
      $('div#second > div').each(function(){
         var sv = $('div').attr('id');
         if (fv.indexOf(sv) > -1){
            // do something
         }
      });
    });
```

Of course am no expert but something along the line.